# svelte: how to use event modifiers in my own components

Tags: event-handling, svelte

I want to developt my own Button component and be able to handle event modifiers, like this:

```
<MyButton on:click|preventDefault={handler}>Click me</MyButton>
```

But I get the following error:

```
Event modifiers other than 'once' can only be used on DOM elementssvelte(invalid-event-modifier)
```

In MyButton I can pass the on:click event like this:

```
<button on:click|preventDefault>
  <slot />
</button>
```

But then I won't be able to use MyButton without the preventDefault

So another option would be to optionally pass event modifiers, to do something like this:

```
<MyButton preventDefault on:click={handler}>Click me</MyButton>
```

And then in MyButton.svelte to something like this (I know this doesn't work) to optionally apply the event modifier.

```
<script>
  export let prevenDefault=false
</script>

<button on:click|{preventDefault ? 'preventDefault' : ''}={handler}>Click me</MyButton>
```

Any idea about how to deal with it?

Comment: As <MyButton> is not a DOM element, you won't be able to add modifiers except "once". Maybe a component for a button is not accurate ? I'm not sure there is any gain about it.

Comment: Why not add preventDefault as a bool prop. In your MyButton componend you can use: event.preventDefault() if the preventDefault prop is true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways that I think are applicable:

1. Preventing default in the event callback (the easier way)
2. Preventing default by passing in a prop (your suggestion)

## Preventing default in the event callback

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
| Easier & cleaner to implement | Consumers of the component will have to call `Event#preventDefault` imperatively |

In order to set this up, you'll need two things.

1. The `<Button>` component to be forwarding its event:

```html
<script>
  // Button.svelte
</script>

<!-- Note that we're not providing any callback, which forwards it -->
<button on:click>
  <slot />
</button>
```

2. The parent component to be calling `Event#preventDefault` on the event:

```html
<script>
  // App.svelte

  import Button from './Button.svelte';
</script>

<Button
  on:click={(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // your code here
  }}
>
  Click Me!
</Button>
```

## Preventing default by passing in a prop

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
| Declaratively add event modifier | Consumers of the component will unwrap the original `Event` object from `CustomEvent#detail` |

You will also need two things here.

1. The `<Button>` component to add its callback manually in the `<script>` tag

```html
<script>
  // Button.svelte

  import {
    onMount,
    onDestroy,
    createEventDispatcher,
  } from 'svelte';

  export let preventDefault = false;

  let button;
  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

  onMount(() => {
    button.addEventListener('click', onClick);
  });

  onDestroy(() => {
    button.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
  });

  function onClick(event) {
    if (preventDefault) event.preventDefault();

    dispatch('click', event);
  }
</script>

<button bind:this={button}>
  <slot />
</button>
```

2. The parent component to pass in the `preventDefault` prop

```html
<script>
  // App.svelte

  import Button from './Button.svelte';
</script>

<Button
  preventDefault
  on:click={({ detail: event }) => {
    // your code here
  })
>
  Click me!
</Button>
```

Comment: This does the job, but looks like a poor workaround. I wish Svelte had a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

**Custom button component**

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let preventDefault: boolean = false;
    export let stopPropagation: boolean = false;
    type MouseEvent = Parameters<MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>>[0];
    type $$Events = {
        click: MouseEvent;
    };
</script>

{#if preventDefault}
    {#if stopPropagation}
        <button {...$$restProps} on:click|preventDefault|stopPropagation
            ><slot /></button>
    {:else}
        <button {...$$restProps} on:click|preventDefault><slot /></button>
    {/if}
{:else if stopPropagation}
    <button {...$$restProps} on:click|stopPropagation><slot /></button>
{:else}
    <button {...$$restProps} on:click><slot /></button>
{/if}
```

**Custom button component usage**

```
<Button
  type="button"
  class="primary-button"
  title="this is a button"
  on:click={onClick}
  preventDefault
  stopPropagation
>
  Send complaint
</Button>
```

If you can endure to insane branch statements drive your brain crazy, this code should achieve what you're looking for. I know. this is really poor workaround. I really want Svelte has a better way of doing this.